# C11 _Generic c program and errors on Eclipse c/c++

Tags: c, generics, gcc

Hi  i was studying C for the first time using C primer plus book  then in chapter 16  about _Generic  from C11 standard i wrote a program in Eclipse c/c++ and build  and it produces 8 errors and warning  and i don't know why here is the program and the errors

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define RAD_TO_DEG (180/(4 * atanl(1)))

// generic square root function
#define SQRT(X) _Generic((X),\
    long double: sqrtl, \
    default: sqrt, \
    float: sqrtf)(X)

// generic sine function, angle in degrees
#define SIN(X) _Generic((X),\
long double: sinl((X)/RAD_TO_DEG),\
default:     sin((X)/RAD_TO_DEG),\
float:       sinf((X)/RAD_TO_DEG)\
)

int main(void)
{
    float x = 45.0f;
    double xx = 45.0;
    long double xxx =45.0L;

    long double y = SQRT(x);
    long double yy= SQRT(xx);
    long double yyy = SQRT(xxx);
    printf("%.17Lf\n", y);   // matches float
    printf("%.17Lf\n", yy);  // matches default
    printf("%.17Lf\n", yyy); // matches long double
    int i = 45;
    yy = SQRT(i);            // matches default
    printf("%.17Lf\n", yy);
    yyy= SIN(xxx);           // matches long double
    printf("%.17Lf\n", yyy);

    return 0;
}
```

errors

```
make all 
Building file: ../generic.c
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
gcc -std=c11 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"generic.d" -MT"generic.d" -o "generic.o" "../generic.c"
../generic.c: In function ‘main’:
../generic.c:24:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘_Generic’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     long double y = SQRT(x);
     ^
../generic.c:7:5: error: expected expression before ‘long’
     long double: sqrtl, \
     ^
../generic.c:24:21: note: in expansion of macro ‘SQRT’
     long double y = SQRT(x);
                     ^
../generic.c:7:5: error: expected expression before ‘long’
     long double: sqrtl, \
     ^
../generic.c:25:21: note: in expansion of macro ‘SQRT’
     long double yy= SQRT(xx);
                     ^
../generic.c:7:5: error: expected expression before ‘long’
     long double: sqrtl, \
     ^
../generic.c:26:23: note: in expansion of macro ‘SQRT’
     long double yyy = SQRT(xxx);
                       ^
../generic.c:7:5: error: expected expression before ‘long’
     long double: sqrtl, \
     ^
../generic.c:31:10: note: in expansion of macro ‘SQRT’
     yy = SQRT(i);            // matches default
          ^
../generic.c:13:1: error: expected expression before ‘long’
 long double: sinl((X)/RAD_TO_DEG),\
 ^
../generic.c:33:10: note: in expansion of macro ‘SIN’
     yyy= SIN(xxx);           // matches long double
          ^
make: *** [generic.o] Error 1

14:47:53 Build Finished (took 66ms)
```

i have used -lm link for math.h and it produces these errors and i don't know why ?

Comment: Which version of GCC do you use? It might not support generics.

Comment: @starrify True, but it may be that the version of GCC used doesn't support *all* of C11, like generics.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg use gcc 4.8.2 working on ubuntu 14.04 LTS eclipse c/c++ developer IDE

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I see. Agreed.

Comment: @BelalMedhat `_Generic` is supported since `gcc 4.9`, see https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/C11Status

Comment: @starrify  Thank you very much       you  answered me so 4.8.2 don't support C11_Generic   then i have to install 4.9     you know i love Linux I like you guys   many people help me saving hours searching for solution to an error  thank you            do you know how to install 4.9 and make it ubuntu default compiler and update it to Eclipse c/c++

Comment: @BelalMedhat AskUbuntu may help as you're using Ubuntu, e.g. http://askubuntu.com/questions/466651/how-do-i-use-the-latest-gcc-4-9-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: @starrify Thank you i will do it now  thank you

Comment: @BelalMedhat It's a pleasure to help. :) Also many thanks to JoachimPileborg too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Reason:

`_Generic` is not supported in `gcc` until version `4.9`, see: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/C11Status

#### Solution:

Try a newer version of `gcc`.

#### Example:

In `a.c` is the code you provided:

```
[pengyu@GLaDOS tmp]$ gcc a.c -std=c11 -lm -Wall -pedantic
[pengyu@GLaDOS tmp]$ gcc --version | head -n 1
gcc (GCC) 4.9.1 20140903 (prerelease)
```

Comment: it really helped me saving time and effort search for strange errors  while everything is right  thank you  pleased to meet you  i will install gcc 4.9 now thank you